# Filter ForeignKey choices in an Admin Form based on selections in same models ManytoMany Field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am making a "matches" model that currently has these fields in them:

```
event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
match_participants = models.ManyToManyField(Wrestler, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True, blank=True,)
match_type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=match_choices, default=BLOCK)
match_result = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=result_choices, default=NOT_OC)
winner = models.ForeignKey(Wrestler, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True, blank=True, related_name="winner")
```

In my scenario the "winner" can only be one of the foreignkeys chosen in "match_participants", I would really like to filter the winner field to only those chosen foreignkeys. Is this possible? I know you can filter foreign key selections based on entries into other models, but not too sure about same table entry.

Here's a UML example of what my database structure currently is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra field in the ManytoMany relationship

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

models.py

```
class Match(models.Model):
    wrestlers = models.ManyToManyField(Wrestler, through='Participation' )
    ...



class Participation(models.Model):
    wrestler = models.ForeignKey(Wrestler, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    winner = models.BooleanField()
```

then for validation you can use a signal to connect to Participation updates, for example

```
def match_wrestlers_changed(sender, *args, **kwargs):
    if invalid:
        raise ValidationError('There already a winner.')

m2m_changed.connect(
    match_wrestlers_changed,
    sender=Match.wrestlers.through)
```

Comment: Thank you, that ended up working perfectly for what I wanted.